# String initialization with + operator java

Tags: java, string

Using + whereas adding new substring to String makes new String object.
How does it work while I would like initialize String with + like that:

```
String str = "Hello " + "world";
```

Will the JVM "take care" of it and make just one String or there will be created two String which will be added into new String? I mean:

1. `String str = new String("Hello") + new String("world");`
2. `String str = "Hello word";`

Which of these codes is true?

Comment: Why do you need to know? Also, the JVM never inserts a `new String(...)`, the Strings exists in the class constant pool.

Comment: Definitely not Number 1. "Hello " and "world" will be in the string pool and a new string will be created that concatenates these two and str will be a reference to this string. In other words your code would be equal to String str = "hello ".operator+("world") where operator+ denotes the method for string concatenation which might create a new string in the heap for you. I said "might" because this can also be optimized by the compiler to create a new string "hello world" in the string pool as it has enough information at compile time and return a reference to it which would equivalent to 2.

Comment: AFAIK, if you put it exactly like this into your source code, i.e. if the strings are not stored in variables but entered directly, the compiler will automatically merge them, i.e. your above code is effectively equivalent to `String str = "Hello word";`. However, I don't have a reference and I don't know if this is the case for all Java implementations, so no answer.

Comment: Just to add the relevant part of the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1.  In short, it's up to the compiler implementation what they do, but _most_ (citation needed, probably all) common ones will go with option 2 as an optimisation.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Just pure curiosity.

Comment: @user2478398 Thanks for the link, still hard for me to find everything in the doc. And you're right as it says: "An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate String object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) manages constant Strings like this:

> A constant expression is an expression denoting ... a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String
> - Parenthesized expressions whose contained expression is a constant expression.
> - Simple names that refer to constant variables.
> - Qualified names of the form `TypeName . Identifier` that refer to constant variables.
>
> Constant expressions of type String are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

Because `String.intern` is called AFTER making the String constant, its literal String components should not be added to the pool.

You can try the `-XX:+PrintStringTableStatistics JVM` option to determine the size of the string pool when your program terminates.

Comment: You could add a reference to [jls-3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) which states that _constant expression_ will be evaluted at compile time ("Strings computed by constant expressions are computed at compile time and then treated as if they were literals.")